# htaccess rewriteRule what is the difference between http://example.com/? and http://example.com/index.php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am interested to avoid a redirection in case of the query string contains a specific format:
?a_aid
So i use this code in the .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^a_aid[NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ /index.php?a=$1 [L]
```

My problem is that it works for the URL:
http://example.com/index.php?a_aid=
but not for the URL:
http://example.com/?a_aid=

Any idea how to support both of them ???

Comment: Where in your rule are you capturing query parameter `54`?

Comment: the value of the parameter is not in the rule...
I need only to avoid the RewriteRule if the the parameter a_aid=
The RewriteCond works only if the url contains index.php...